# Can I Write A Story Within The Forgotten Realms And Publish it?

Tags: races, forgotten-realms, publishing, intellectual-property

If I were to use a character, say a Deva, and create a story using them can I publish it?

For things like town names, God titles and small amounts of lore I can change them. But the real question is, are Deva (a playable race within the 4e and 3.5e games) copyrighted?

I have a premise of a Deva losing his Ancestral Memories and trying to figure out why his connection with Selune, the moon Goddess, is missing. But at the same time this also means that I would need some kind of idea on if Selune, Deva's and other such things are copyrighted.

Comment: This ain't Law, so I don't think you'll get a good answer here. Dig up some stuff on the intricacies of copyright as far as fan works go.

Comment: This belongs on Law.SE - I agree with TuggyNE

Comment: I'm voting to re-open. The question is about publishing protocols for a specific RPG franchise belonging to a company that publishes exactly this sort of thing. Users with experience in RPG-related publishing can offer specific insights which folks with a general understanding of the laws cannot. [Repeated](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3295/4398) meta discussions [make it clear](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5564/4398) that RPG-specific law (and [publishing](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/609/4398)) questions [are on topic](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5632/4398) here.

Comment: This is so on topic that it's been answered before.

Answer (score 1):

I'd encourage you to get someone with official copyright hold over Deva answer this. Perhaps even here.

### Copyright

The name itself cannot be copyrighted, but **character** can and most likely is.
More info here: [Are the Gods in Forgotten Realms under copyright?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/47443/are-the-gods-in-forgotten-realms-under-copyright)

### L5R and AEG, if it's any indicator

From my own experience with AEG and L5R, the answer was:

- awesome you are doing it
- not officially, as a book with ISBN, sorry, that's policy, we don't endorse anything like it
- go for fanfic!

So (note: AEG + L5R), self-published, via internet or with so called "small print", not as in catch in a contract, but publishing a book with small number of copies (enough not to have book number).

Been a while since, so my answer may be wrong. I'll try digging up the email once I have more time.

### Update: Forgotten Realm's novel

See this question it seems to be about similar case: https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/17060/novel-set-in-forgotten-realms-universe